# Keep generic type based on passed data, instead of default value, when sibling generic is specified

Tags: typescript

In unit tests I don't need to be very strict and I want a dynamic generic type that would allow me to skip type cast.

I want `T` to be anything, but if I specify it - I should get exact type.

I want `R` to be exactly the type of `params`, regardless whether T was specified or not.

The problem is - once I specify `T`, I have to specify `R`, I added its default value `{ [key: string]: any }`, but it breaks types and doesn't respect correctly `params` type.

```js
declare function test<T, R extends { [key: string]: any } = { [key: string]: any }>(
  template: string,
  params: R,
): {t: T, r: R};

// test without specified generics
const test1 = test('f', {
  a: 'a',
});

test1.t; // as expected - unknown, because I didn't specify it.
test1.r.a; // as expected - works, it's a string
test1.r.b; // as expected - fails, it doesn't exist

// test with a specified generic
const test2 = test<string>('f', {
  a: 'a',
});

test2.t; // as expected - string
test2.r.a; // failed - it's any, not string anymore
test2.r.b; // failed - it's any, not forbidden anymore

// I'm trying kind of
declare function anotherTest<T>(
  template: string,
  params: { [key: string]: any },
): {t: T, r: typeof params}; // I want the passed type, not { [key: string]: any }
```

I guess there's not a way to do so without moving params as an independent variable and specifying its type, perhaps you know a solution.
Thanks in advance!

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwxAGcMAeAFQBp4AleEAD0NWCPgG94BtAaxAE8AXPBIwsqAOYBdYVFT94AX3gBeDtz5CRGMZJnw5CxQD4AFACh4BEAFsADtELDR4iZUvw7sKDaLCa7gCUwuwYwlTwMP6KANzm5gD0CdYk8ADuWBgAFjjIGCJ24FiIWCDA8BIgqCBiYETmYHiphCQAjKopGKYA5Ijd1OweUMLdUP3mioFx5i0YrQB0GDHwSQZsjIWYZfAAtPBoPKg4aagzxHPzMPNQy6tQ6wybhOV7aTgwPETUmd1sUNq6CRnNqXeYAI1uyXu9Ee4GeuyQUCwEC+8Ey8GAOGIqG6+UYWBI8VWs3SmSyBgKRRK20q1VqDSa+VmACYOrNSC5JGZev0OEMRmN3JNpizFpC1jCnts9pygaKrjcVslEEiINK0RhfgZ5NQjvlZcCMMzQRClYjkeqfn8dfA9Uh3mCsMBQKcgA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it's impossible, but good news is that it's under development:

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10571
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26349

a possible solution will be like that: leading `infer` is the magic.

```js
type TypeConstraint = string | boolean;
function getName<A, infer B extends TypeConstraint>(a: A, b: B): B {}

// ok
const abc: boolean = getName<string>("abc", true);
const abc: boolean = getName<string, boolean>("abc", true);

// error
const abc: boolean = getName<string>("abc", 10);
```